# A question regarding compact Hausdorff spaces.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, compactness

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Suppose that $U\subseteq X$ is open and $p\in U$. I want to show that there is an open set $V$ such that $p\in V$ and $\overline{V}\subseteq U$.

So far I've tried considering an open cover $\mathcal{A}$ of $X$ and using the fact that $X$ is compact to obtain a finite subcover $\mathcal{A}_0$ and then letting $\tilde{\mathcal{A}_0}=\mathcal{A}_0\cup\{U\}$. Now, let $V=\bigcap\{A\in\tilde{\mathcal{A}_0}\colon p\in A\}$. I'm trying to show that $\overline{V}\subseteq U$.

I don't know if I'm going on the right track. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $U$ is open, $U^\complement$ is closed, and therefore compact. For each $x\in U^\complement$, let $U_x$ be an open neighborhood of $p$ and let $V_x$ be an open neighborhood of $x$ such that $U_x\cap V_x=\emptyset$. We have$$U^\complement=\bigcup_{x\in U^\complement}\{x\}\subset\bigcup_{x\in U^\complement}V_x.$$So, $\left\{V_x\mid x\in U^\complement\right\}$ is an open cover of $U^\complement$. Take $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}\subset U^\complement$ such that$$U^\complement\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^nV_{x_i}.\tag1$$Then $V=\bigcap_{i=1}^nU_{x_i}$ is an open neighborhood of $p$. Besides,$$V\cap\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^nV_{x_i}\right)=\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^nU_{x_i}\right)\cap\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^nV_{x_i}\right)=\emptyset;$$in other words, $V\subset\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^nV_{x_i}\right)^\complement$. But then, since $\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^nV_{x_i}\right)^\complement$ is a closed set,$$\overline V\subset\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^nV_{x_i}\right)^\complement\subset\left(U^\complement\right)^\complement=U.$$